# M1 Mac: Java Jar file throws (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), how to fix it?

Tags: java, macos, apple-m1

I was running bash scripts that run different Java JAR files on old Mac that has x86 architecture on terminal. Now, I moved my project to new Mac that has M1 chip. All Java JAR files are running perfectly except one JAR file. It throws this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  while
> loading kognac-core:
> /private/var/folders/nk/mg7msvvx4rg7d9bht0l7lnwr0000gp/T/VLog-tmp3418712731783893816/libkognac-core.dylib:
> dlopen(/private/var/folders/nk/mg7msvvx4rg7d9bht0l7lnwr0000gp/T/VLog-tmp3418712731783893816/libkognac-core.dylib,
> 0x0001): tried:
> '/private/var/folders/nk/mg7msvvx4rg7d9bht0l7lnwr0000gp/T/VLog-tmp3418712731783893816/libkognac-core.dylib'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libkognac-core.dylib' (no such file)

I searched for solutions and I tried:

1. Make sure that Java JDK is x86 not arm64 by running: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
   output:

   ```
   Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
       18.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 18.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
       1.8.202.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
       1.8.0_202 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```
2. I tried to run the terminal with x86_64 instead of arm64 architecture by this commands:

   ```bash
   env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh —-login
   ```

However, the error is still there. How can I fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing libkognac arm64 code.   you need to recompile that lib for arm64 apparently.

Comment: How could I do that? the code is on GitHub. I download the code then compiled it on M1 Mac, but nothing changed.

Comment: Which code did you compile on M1... there is x86_64 stuff all over the place...